# SQL ERROR "1 near 'inner', Syntax Error" W3C sample database

Tags: sql, inner-join, w3c

```
select OD.orderID, C.CustomerName, O.OrderDate,          
    round(sum(P.Price*OD.Quantity)) as TotalPrice 
inner join OrderDetails as OD on OD.OrderID=O.OrderID 
inner join Products as P on OD.ProductID=P.ProductID 
inner join Customers as C on O.CustomerID=C.CustomerID 
group by OD.OrderID 
Order by TotalPrice 
limit 5
```

Here's my SQL statement. It gives me 'inner' syntax error...
Can I ask what's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your SQL statement is missing the `FROM` clause:

```
select OD.orderID, C.CustomerName, O.OrderDate,          
  round(sum(P.Price*OD.Quantity)) as TotalPrice 
FROM <your driving table here>
inner ...
```

Presumably, you want to select from `Orders`:

```
select OD.orderID, C.CustomerName, O.OrderDate,          
  round(sum(P.Price*OD.Quantity)) as TotalPrice 
FROM Orders as O
inner ...
```